# Is reusing project reactor publisher Flux/Mono considered a best practice?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

Project Reactor publisher Flux/Mono are reusable. We can subscribe multiple time to the same publisher. By doing that we avoid useless object creation but i feel like it make the code harder to read in some case.

Is there specific argument that encourage to reuse Flux/Mono ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There’s no best practice as such. A reactive publisher is not “reusable” in general. Depends on whether the it is a hot or cold source. You can, or course, cache some elements if you need to.
For example, if your source is emitting the stock prices for a company, it makes no sense to cache or reuse the historical prices (unless for analysis but that’s irrelevant).

Comment: I'd expect a majority of Flux/Mono to be cold though, and hot publishers can easily be made cold (ie. per-subscription) by wrapping them in `defer`